# Using Multiple Transaction in a Single Hibernate Session

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, web-applications, transactions

I have an web application with MySQL DB and Hibernate. 
I have open a Hibernate Session,

***started a transaction***

***do some work***

***commit the transaction***

Then again

***started a transaction***

***do some work***

***commit the transaction***

But I am ended with following exception

**Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started Transaction not successfully started.**

Please guide me in this specific issue. How can I use multiple transaction within a Session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not starting your transaction. That is when you get that exception. You have opened a session, but before beginning transaction, you are committing it. Try beginning it after you open the session.

```
// create session
try {    
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    // do something
    tx.commit();
} catch (Exception exp) {
    tx.rollback();

}

try {    
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    // do something
    tx.commit();
} catch (Exception exp) {
    tx.rollback();

}
// close session
```